# Running total with group by in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get a running balance of payouts in a table that will be displayed in a transaction list. The sum of each payout on the left and the running total (accumulated balance) to the right.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT *, SUM(payment_sum) as total, @running_total := @running_total
 + payment_sum AS cumulative_sum FROM payments JOIN
(SELECT @running_total := 0)t WHERE id=? 
GROUP BY source, report_date;
```

The payment_sum and the cumulative_sum (running total) is correct unless I group by source and report_date. Then, the payment_sum is correct but the running total is not. I need to group by source and report_date as a payment from the same source may occur on the same date, so I would like to group all payments from the same source together to not display them twice. This causes the running total to give a false balance. it seems to only total the first group of the sources.

output without source grouped (correct balance):

```
Source   date      payout  balance
Google   10/18/18    $5.00  $ 5.00
Google   10/18/18    $5.00  $10.00
Amazon   10/18/18    $2.50  $12.50
Amazon   10/18/18    $2.50  $15.00
WebStore 10/18/18    $2.00  $17.00
```

output with source grouped (incorrect balance):

```
Source   date      payout  balance
Google   10/18/18    $10.00  $ 5.00
Amazon   10/18/18    $ 5.00  $ 7.50
WebStore 10/18/18    $ 2.00  $ 9.50
```

Desired output:(source, report_date grouped)

```
Source   date      payout  balance
Google   10/18/18    $10.00  $10.00
Amazon   10/18/18    $ 5.00  $15.00
WebStore 10/18/18    $ 2.00  $17.00
```

Any ideas on how to better format my query for the desired results?

Comment: what should be your expected output as per the given sample data ?

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear of the current and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the result-set of `group by` operation in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and then compute the running balance.

Also, note that I have done proper [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) for code clarity (readability), and avoid ambiguous operations.

Try the following:

```
SELECT dt.*, 
       @running_total := @running_total + dt.total AS cumulative_sum 
FROM (
      SELECT t1.*, 
             SUM(t1.payment_sum) as total 
      FROM payments AS t1 
      WHERE t1.id = ? 
      GROUP BY t1.source, t1.report_date 
     ) AS dt 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) AS t2
```

Comment: This query just duplicates the payment_sum to the cumulative sum. the new "balance" column is identical to the payment_sum now.

Comment: @SonnyKing where is the balance column in my query ? Anyways wait, I have an alternative approach. Editing soon

Comment: @running_total is aliased as cumulative_sum, that's the running "balance". There is no physical column for it.

Comment: This works as expected! I tried it this way before but not the cross join at the end. been banging my head against the desk for hours trying to work it out, THANKS!

Comment: @SonnyKing happy to help :) We have all passed through such times ;) Sometimes taking a break helps, and let mind refocus.

Comment: How would you accomplish this same thing after they remove the support for assigning user variables in select statements?

Comment: @JohnC Even if that happens, it will happen after MySQL 8 only, as the latest version till date supports them. Now, the good thing is that since MySQL 8, we already have the facility of Window Functions available now, for achieving the solution of this problem.

Comment: So can you show an example using these new functions?

Comment: All I get is a column of null values